# simple Jquery script not working :/

Tags: jquery

im having problem with this script i made, its not working and i dont know what am i doing wrong.

When i click the text between 'span' tags the script should insert it into the 'input text' but nothing happens.

Hope you can solve my problem

Thanks!

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
    var $tagsInput = $("#message");
    $("span").click(function() {
        $tagsInput[0].value += $(this).text();
        return false;
    });
</script>

<input type="text" id="message" size="83" />
<div class="iconos" style="border: 1px solid #DDDDDD; font-size: 16px; padding: 3px; width:400px; word-wrap: break-word; float:right;margin-right: 150px; ">
<span>&#x1F604;</span>
<span>&#x1F60A;</span></div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because you try to bind event handlers to elements that don't yet exist.

Either put the script element at the bottom of the body or change it to

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
    $(function(){
      var $tagsInput = $("#message");
      $("span").click(function() {
        $tagsInput[0].value += $(this).text();
        return false;
      });
    });
</script>
```

See [.ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Comment: @Jacedc $tagsInput[0] returns the first element in the selector as a DOM element.

Comment: @Jacedc OP probably used this because it's a little longer to write with `val` when you do a +=, even when using a function as callback.

Comment: its because there many span tags so depends in which i clicked it will display one or other.

Works like a charm

Thanks!! :)